# MDC: drawer.open is not initialized when browser's back button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, mdc-components

I want to use [drawer](https://material.io/develop/web/components/drawers/). I wrote the basic code such that when user clicks nav button, the drawer.open is toggled (i.e. true, false, true, false, ...). However, if user goes to other page by clicking a link in drawer menu and comes back by clicking browser's back button, drawer.open is true and user can not click browser's nav button.

1. User opens the page: `drawer.open=false`.
2. User clicks the nav button: `drawer.open=true` .
3. User clicks a link in the menu: `drawer.open=false` in new page.
4. User clicks browser's back button and comes back: `drawer.open=true` .

Why is `drawer.open=true` in 4.? How do I fix this?

Comment: Try `drawer.open = !drawer.open` instead. See an example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731777/material-components-for-the-web-modal-drawer-example-using-cdns#52769302

Answer (score 0):

Reload the page to initialize JavaScript variables when user clicks browser's back button.

```
<script>
        window.onpageshow = function(event) {
            if (event.persisted) {
                 window.location.reload();
            }
        };
</script>
```